# Prevent images querying from passing through index.php

Tags: image, magento

My issue is pretty much summed up in the title of my question. I noticed in debug mode that images querying was passing through index.php (cf: screenshot below ).

[image]

Is there a way to prevent that ?

We're using Nginx.

Comment: This file is exists in your file system or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the request targer does not exist (file/directory does not exists in the file system) then request is redirected into index.php by default.